# UINavigationBar Back button duplicates twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have used the following code in my `appDelegate` and customizing back bar button goes well. When i used `segue` for the controllers `navigation` `backbarbutton` appears twice.

```
UIImage *buttonPortait = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-icon"]
                              resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0, 0,0)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonPortait
                                                      forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[UIBarButtonItem.appearance setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -64) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I also used `navigationBar setTranslucent:NO` but yet the problem surviving. Any solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution by altering the image size for the back bar button.
I used image size with height 30x(non-retina)/60x(retina) and width 90x(non-retina)/180x(retina)

cheers!!!

Comment: Weird fixed, but I used same it.